# Shortcut to turn Wi-Fi on/off on Samsung Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-nexus, app-widgets

Since the sync utility I use to sync my Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Outlook only supports Wi-Fi instead of USB, I searched the AppStore for an application that adds a shortcut on the screen to make it easier to turn Wi-Fi on and off.

I tried [DroidMania](http://www.droid-mania.com/)'s, but it doesn't seem to work (when clicking on the icon, it simply displays a text page). Next, I tried [Hotspot Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mysandbox.android.hotspotwidget), but nothing happens when I click on the shortcut. Other apps seem old, are only 1.0, and might not work either.

Hard to believe something that simple couldn't be found easily.

Does anyone know of a very simple application that

1. Simply adds a shortcut on the screen to do this.
2. And, definitely works on the Samsung Galaxy Nexus?

Comment: Don't the standard widgets work for this case? I do not have a Nexus device, but all my devices have a Wifi toggle widget by default (AFAIK this already comes with AOSP). Just long-tap on an empty space on your homescreen, select *Widgets*, and check the list. Next to a single stand-alone Wifi widget, there's usually also a combined "power-widget" which includes a Wifi toggle.

Answer (score 10):

On the Samsung Galaxy Nexus, you can add the Android built-in "Power Control" widget to your screen, this has a one-click button for turning Wifi on and off on the left-hand end of the bar.

[image: Power Bar on Jellybean Galaxy Nexus]

*(screen shot is from the home screen of my Galaxy Nexus, but this power bar has been built-in to Android since at least v1.6, though some manufacturer customizations do remove/change it)*

To add this press the circle-with-dots-in icon at the bottom of the home screen to go to your apps list, then select the "**WIDGETS**" tab at the top of the screen and scroll along until you see "Power Control" or "Settings", hold your finger down on that and it should allow you to drag that to an empty spot on one of your home screens.

Also, if you've received the Jelly Bean 4.2.1 update, it contains a quick settings menu that allows you to get right into the Wi-Fi page in settings. You can swipe down with two fingers from the notification bar, or swipe once and click the button in the top righthand corner.

[image: Link to the settings menu from the notification shade]

Then you long-press on the Wifi icon to turn it on or off.

[image: Wifi toggle]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Android ICS you can simply drag the notification area and turn wifi on/off from there.

Comment: That option is not available in Galaxy Nexus, at least there's no such a thing in my phone.

Comment: I can confirm that it works on my Galaxy Nexus. @GAThrawn's answer shows how it should work.